# C# parse XML Schema (SimpleType) question

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Good day.

I can handle a ComplexType such as:

```
  <xsd:element name="Prerequisite">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Type" type="Prerequisite.Type.type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="Miscellaneous" type="Prerequisite.Misc.type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

My C# like this below:

```
    // Get the sequence particle of the complex type.
    XmlSchemaSequence sequence = complexType.ContentTypeParticle as XmlSchemaSequence;

    if (sequence != null)
    {
        // Iterate over each XmlSchemaElement in the Items collection.
        foreach (XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element: {0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", 
                              childElement.QualifiedName.Name,
                              childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, 
                              childElement.MinOccurs, 
                              childElement.MaxOccurs);
        }
    }
```

But i don't know how to handle the "restriction" and "enumeration"?
Could you please give me some guide. thanks in advance.

```
  <xsd:simpleType name="SystemTypeEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="Etch" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

**XmlSchemaSequence**  ->  I Can't find the class of **XmlSchemaRestriction**

**XmlSchemaElement** -> I Can't find the class of **XmlSchemaEnumeration too**.

:-(

========================= Need Further Help. THANKS. ========================

@ `foreach (XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet childEnumeration in ????);`

I still don't know how to complete the top line.
  Could you give me further help?

```
        XmlSchemaSimpleType simpleType = xsdType as XmlSchemaSimpleType;
        Console.WriteLine("simpleType: {0}", xsdType.Name);
        XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction restriction = simpleType.Content as XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction;

        if (restriction != null)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("restriction : {0}", restriction.BaseTypeName.Name);

            foreach (XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet childEnumeration in ????)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element: {0}", childEnumeration.Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Tomalak for added a tag of "xml-shcema".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [`XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemasimpletyperestriction.aspx) and [`XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaenumerationfacet.aspx).

The question "[Extract enumeration values from xsd schema file in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787745/extract-enumeration-values-from-xsd-schema-file-in-net)" discusses the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
    XmlSchemaSimpleType simpleType = xsdType as XmlSchemaSimpleType;
    Console.WriteLine("simpleType: {0}", xsdType.Name);
    XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction restriction = simpleType.Content as XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction;

    if (restriction != null)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("restriction : {0}", restriction.BaseTypeName.Name);

        foreach (XmlSchemaObject facet in restriction.Facets)
        {
            if (facet is XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet)

            Console.WriteLine("Element: {0}", ((XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet)facet).Value);
        }
    }
```